# Parsing a file with strings and integers c#

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have been given a simple task, that I cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish it.

I have been given a text file that has both names and pay rate/hours of employees. The format is as follows:

```
Mary Jones
12.50 30
Bill Smith
10.00 40
Sam Brown
9.50 40
```

My task is to write a program that uses StreamReader to pull the data from a text file, then print the employees name, and calculate the total pay by multiplying the rate and hours.

I know how to split the line with a .Split method, however I can't seem to figure out how to seperate the names from the doubles/ints. My parse methods always come back with a format error because it reads the strings first. I am completely stuck.

Here is my code so far, any help or guidance would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace lab21
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            StreamReader myfile = new StreamReader("data.txt");
            string fromFile;

            do
            {
                fromFile = myfile.ReadLine();
                if (fromFile != null)
                {
                    string[] payInfo = fromFile.Split( );
                    double wage = double.Parse(payInfo[0]);
                    int hours = int.Parse(payInfo[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(fromFile);
                    Console.WriteLine(wage * hours);
                }
            } while (fromFile != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Decimal.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y1z063b) and **`read two line`**:

```
do
{
    name = myfile.ReadLine();
    if (name != null)
    {
        // read second line
        var nums = myfile.ReadLine();
        if (nums != null)
        {
            string[] payNums = nums.Split(new[] {' '});
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", 
                              name,
                              Decimal.Parse(payNums[0])
                              * Decimal.Parse(payNums[1]));
        }
    }
} while (name != null);
```

Comment: Why are you splitting a line with just names, and calling it `payInfo`? That's misleading. I would also suggest that splitting out the "reading" from "parsing" makes the code more flexible and easier to test.

Answer (score 5):

You're only reading a single line in the loop. An employee record appear to consist of *two* lines - so you need to read both of them on each iteration. (Alternatively you could keep track of which line you were up to, but that would be painful.) I would rewrite the loop as something like:

```
string name;
while ((name = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string payText = reader.ReadLine();
    if (payText == null)
    {
        // Or whatever exception you want to throw...
        throw new InvalidDataException("Odd number of lines in file");
    }
    Employee employee = ParseTextValues(name, payText);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", employee.Name, employee.Hours * employee.Wage);
}
```

Then have a separate method for parsing the two values, which will make it easier to test.

When you're parsing, note that you should use `decimal` rather than `double` to represent currency values.

Comment: Exact same thing that occurred to me. The code in the question only reads one line at a a time. which means that when he reads an employee's name it will end up being parsed as an integer as well. Though, this kind of thing would be caught if the OP had tried to use the debugger in VS. I wonder if he knows how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use int.TryParse(string, out int) (both int and double). If it fails, you probably have a string, otherwise, you're in luck.

With this data, where you know every second line is a string, you should probably put that in the code too, you could have a index/count, and when that is uneven, you should expect a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. Very simple modifications.

```
do
{
    fromFile = myfile.ReadLine();
    fromFile += @" " + myfile.ReadLine();
    if (fromFile != null)
    {
         string[] payInfo = fromFile.Split( );
         double wage = double.Parse(payInfo[2]);
         int hours = int.Parse(payInfo[3]);
         Console.WriteLine(fromFile);
         Console.WriteLine(wage * hours);
    }
} while (fromFile != null);
```